# Using Cholesky factorization to solve the system $AXA=B$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I have been given a problem of solving $X$, which is an unblurred image, in the system:
$$B = A X A \iff X = A^{-1} B A^{-1},$$
where matrix $A$ describes the blurring of an image and matrix $B$ is the blurred image.

Matrices $A$ and $B$ are given and it is known that $A$ is symmetrical and positive definite. This leads me to believe that Cholesky factorization is a good method to apply.

The only problem is that the assignment specifies that it wants a solution where only one factorization is used. As I see it two total factorizations are needed. One is used when solving $B = AX$ and then one more for the final matrix $A$ which then gives an unblurred image. Am I missing a way to rewrite the problem so that only factorization has to be used?

Comment: Why would you need more than one factorization? You factorize $A$ and use this factorization on both sides of $B$. It's certainly better than to use the [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Matrix_equations).